# How to send arbitrary FTP commands in C#

Tags: c#, ftp, ftpwebrequest

I have implemented the ability to upload, download, delete, etc. using the `FtpWebRequest` class in C#.  That is fairly straight forward.

What I need to do now is support sending arbitrary FTP commands such as

```
quote SITE LRECL=132 RECFM=FB
or 
quote SYST
```

Here's an example configuration straight from our `app.config`:

```xml
<!-- The following commands will be executed before any uploads occur -->
<extraCommands>
     <command>quote SITE LRECL=132 RECFM=FB</command>
</extraCommands>
```

I'm still researching how to do this using `FtpWebRequest`.   I'll probably try `WebClient` class next.  Anyone can point me in the right direction quicker?  Thanks!

UPDATE:
I've come to that same conclusion, as of .NET Framework 3.5 `FtpWebRequest` doesn't support anything except what's in [`WebRequestMethods.Ftp.*`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequestmethods.ftp_members.aspx).  I'll try a third party app recommended by some of the other posts.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Did you try Rebex FTP with those commands? did it work well?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think it can be done with `FtpWebRequest`... The only way to specify a FTP command is through the `Method` property, and the documentation states :

> Note that the strings defined in the `WebRequestMethods.Ftp` class are the only supported options for the `Method` property. Setting the `Method` property to any other value will result in an `ArgumentException` exception.

SITE and SYST are not among the predefined options, so I guess you're stuck...

Don't waste time to try the `WebClient` class, it will give you even less flexibility than `FtpWebRequest`.

However, there are plenty of third-party FTP implementation, open source or commercial, and I'm pretty sure some of them can handle custom commands...

Answer (score 8):

The `FtpWebRequest` won't help you as [Thomas Levesque](https://stackoverflow.com/users/98713/thomas-levesque) has said in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2321799/2042090). You can use some third party solutions or the following, simplified `TcpClient` based code which I have refactored from an [answer written in Visual Basic](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d542b0b7-8cb9-4705-9403-92296da5f9cb/ftpwebrequest-and-custom-commands?forum=netfxnetcom):

```
public static void SendFtpCommand()
{
    var serverName = "[FTP_SERVER_NAME]";
    var port = 21;
    var userName = "[FTP_USER_NAME]";
    var password = "[FTP_PASSWORD]"
    var command = "SITE CHMOD 755 [FTP_FILE_PATH]";

    var tcpClient = new TcpClient();
    try
    {
        tcpClient.Connect(serverName, port);
        Flush(tcpClient);

        var response = TransmitCommand(tcpClient, "user " + userName);
        if (response.IndexOf("331", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) < 0)
            throw new Exception(string.Format("Error \"{0}\" while sending user name \"{1}\".", response, userName));

        response = TransmitCommand(tcpClient, "pass " + password);
        if (response.IndexOf("230", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) < 0)
            throw new Exception(string.Format("Error \"{0}\" while sending password.", response));

        response = TransmitCommand(tcpClient, command);
        if (response.IndexOf("200", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) < 0)
            throw new Exception(string.Format("Error \"{0}\" while sending command \"{1}\".", response, command));
    }
    finally
    {
        if (tcpClient.Connected)
            tcpClient.Close();
    }
}

private static string TransmitCommand(TcpClient tcpClient, string cmd)
{
    var networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
    if (!networkStream.CanWrite || !networkStream.CanRead)
        return string.Empty;

    var sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(cmd + "\r\n");
    networkStream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length);

    var streamReader = new StreamReader(networkStream);
    return streamReader.ReadLine();
}

private static string Flush(TcpClient tcpClient)
{
    try
    {
        var networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
        if (!networkStream.CanWrite || !networkStream.CanRead)
            return string.Empty;

        var receiveBytes = new byte[tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize];
        networkStream.ReadTimeout = 10000;
        networkStream.Read(receiveBytes, 0, tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize);

        return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveBytes);
    }
    catch
    {
        // Ignore all irrelevant exceptions
    }

    return string.Empty;
}
```

You can expect the following flow while getting through the FTP:

```
220 (vsFTPd 2.2.2)
user [FTP_USER_NAME]
331 Please specify the password.
pass [FTP_PASSWORD]
230 Login successful.
SITE CHMOD 755 [FTP_FILE_PATH]
200 SITE CHMOD command ok.
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try our [Rebex FTP component](http://www.rebex.net/ftp.net/):

```
// create client and connect 
Ftp client = new Ftp();
client.Connect("ftp.example.org");
client.Login("username", "password");

// send SITE command
// note that QUOTE and SITE are ommited. QUOTE is command line ftp syntax only.
client.Site("LRECL=132 RECFM=FB");

// send SYST command
client.SendCommand("SYST");
FtpResponse response = client.ReadResponse();
if (response.Group != 2) 
  ; // handle error 

// disconnect 
client.Disconnect();
```

Answer (score -5):

Use `sendCommand("SITE LRECL=242 BLKSIZE=0 RECFM=FB");`

Comment: This is very unhelpful because no information is provided.  What is "sendCommand"  is it a 3rd party library, does it have something to do with FtpWebRequest???