# FtpWebRequest error: 550 Size not allowed in ASCII mode

Tags: c#, ftp, binary, ascii, ftpwebrequest

I'm trying to get the file size from a remote FTP file through anonymous FTP.

```
public static long GetSize(string ftpPath)
{
    try
    {
        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(ftpPath));
        request.Proxy = null;
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("anonymous", "´");
        request.UseBinary = true;
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.GetFileSize;

        FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        long size = response.ContentLength;
        response.Close();
        return size;
    }
    catch (WebException e)
    {
        string status = ((FtpWebResponse)e.Response).StatusDescription;
        MessageBox.Show(status);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

This currently returns the error "550 Size not allowed in ASCII mode." I'm aware that I have to use binary mode, but setting `UseBinary` to true (see above) doesn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, I think you may be stuck.  The `WebRequestMethods.Ftp` class, per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321097/how-to-send-arbitrary-ftp-commands-in-c-sharp), will not support sending FTP commands other than the supported ones -- and for your use case, you would need your client to send "TYPE I" (for "image" or binary mode) before sending the SIZE command.

Alternatively, as a hacky workaround, you might try download a file -- any file -- before sending your SIZE command.  With `request.UseBinary = true` for *that* request, it should cause your client to send the "TYPE I" command to the FTP server.  (And it won't matter if that download request fails; the TYPE command will still have been sent.)  Most FTP servers, upon receiving a TYPE command, will *assume* that TYPE for subsequent commands.  Then, when you try the `GetFileSize` request again, the FTP server *might* be in binary, not ASCII mode, and your SIZE command might succeed.